# Overlapped bit-field in C

Tags: c, struct, unions, bit-fields

I'm a computer science student.

Now, I'm working on a computer architecture project in C, which simulates a processor.

There are many types of instructions such as

```
 31     27 26     22 21     17 16                              0
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
|    op   |    ra   |    rb   |             imm17               |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------

 31     27 26     22 21     17 16                7 6 5 4       0
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
|    op   |    ra   |    rb   |       imm10       | m |  shamt  |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------

 31     27 26     22 21                                        0
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
|    op   |    ra   |                  imm22                    |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, I wanted to make a C structure which contains bit-fields corresponding to each elements such as op, ra and so on.

At first, I thought that I could use unions and nested structs.

For example, I wrote code like:

```
struct instr_t {
    union {
        uint32_t imm22 : 22;

        struct {
            union {
                uint32_t imm17: 17;
                struct {
                    uint8_t shamt: 5;
                    uint8_t mode : 2;
                    uint16_t imm10 : 10;
                };
            };
            uint8_t rb : 5;
        };
    };

    uint8_t ra : 5;
    uint8_t op : 5;
}
```

I expected that the result of sizeof(struct instr_t) would be 4 but the reality was 12.

Maybe the nested structs got some paddings.

So, here is my qeustion:

#### How can one achieve overlapped C bit-fields?

or

#### Does anybody can recommend a better way to implement multiple types of instruction in C?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use a single unsigned integer that can hold your bits?

Comment: @2501 Could you explain more in detail please?

Comment: Depending on operating system, an 8 bit integer could easily be 16 or 32 bits.

Comment: @JoeManiaci I very highly doubt that. :)

Comment: I think what 2501 is saying is to use a 32 bit integer and use bit-wise operations to set the values that you need.

Comment: Have one `struct instr_t{...}` with 4 unioned entries: a sub-`struct{...} R`, a sub-`struct{...} I`, a sub-`struct{...} J` and a `uint32_t asInt32`. Ergo: `struct instr_t{union{struct{/* Fields of R-type */} R; struct{/* Fields of I-type */} I; struct{/* Fields of J-type */} J; uint32_t asInt32;};};`

Comment: @2501 - Usually no, but it is possible depending on implementation. I actually should clarify, what you declare to be a short could be, depending on system, larger than what you would expect. Obviously an 8-bit integer is an 8-bit integer.

Comment: @JoeManiaci An 8 bit integer is by definition 8 bit.

Comment: @JoeManiaci I have considered to use bit-wise operation to extract each element. But I just wanted to try something different :)

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Then should I access to each element like instr.type1.op?

Comment: @ibyeoksan Exactly: Say you had `struct instr_t instr;` You'd access it as `instr.R.shamt` for instance.

Comment: 2 recommendations! bit-wise operation and union of each instruction struct. Thank you guys. I prefer latter one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bit-fields members must be stored in the same storage unit to be layed out contiguously:

```
struct instr_1_t {
    uint32_t imm22 : 17;
    uint32_t rb : 5;
    uint32_t ra : 5;
    uint32_t op : 5;
};

struct instr_2_t {
    uint32_t shamt: 5;
    uint32_t m: 2;
    uint32_t imm10 : 10;
    uint32_t rb : 5;
    uint32_t ra : 5;
    uint32_t op : 5;
};

struct instr_3_t {
    uint32_t imm22 : 22;
    uint32_t ra : 5;
    uint32_t op : 5;
};

union instr_t {
    struct {
        uint32_t pad : 22;
        uint32_t op : 5;
    };
    instr_1_t instr_1;
    instr_2_t instr_2;
    instr_3_t instr_3;
};

static_assert(sizeof(instr_t) == sizeof(uint32_t), "sizeof(instr_t) != sizeof(uint32_t)");

void handle_instr(instr_t i) {
    switch(i.op) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, that if you reverse the order of bit-fields, you would not need to pad `op` in `instr_t` manually.

Comment: Updated answer! I like it :)

Answer (score 5):

Maxim gave the correct answer.

I also suggest looking over this code to understand why sizeof instr_t was giving 12 :)

```
typedef struct s1{
    uint8_t shamt: 5;
    uint8_t mode : 2;
    uint16_t imm10 : 10;
} s_1;

typedef union u1{
    uint32_t imm17: 17;
    s_1 member0;
} u_1;

typedef struct s2{
    u_1 member1;
    uint8_t rb : 5;
} s_2;

typedef union u2{
    uint32_t imm22 : 22;
    s_2 member3;
} u_2;

typedef struct instr_t {
    u_2 member4;
    uint8_t ra : 5;
    uint8_t op : 5;
} s_instr;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("sizes s_1=%d, u_1=%d, s_2=%d, u_2=%d, s_instr=%d\n", sizeof(s_1), sizeof(u_1), sizeof(s_2), sizeof(u_2), sizeof(s_instr)); 
    printf("uint8_t=%d, uint16_t=%d, uint32_t=%d\n", sizeof(uint8_t), sizeof(uint16_t), sizeof(uint32_t));
    printf("Sizeof instr_t is %d\n", sizeof(s_instr));
}
```

Hope this helps!

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! I think it's because of byte-alignment. I've never consider it.

Answer (score -2):

Bitfields are not portable. You never know if the same bitfield definition gets you the same results on two different compilers. Bitfields also have let's say interesting semantics in multi-threaded programs.

Go with C++ and write a class with appropriated inlined accessors. I mean you are a computer science student, you know C++, right?

If for some mad reason your superiors demand that the code is written in C, write a struct with one uint32_t member and individual accessor functions using shift and masking operations. Obviously also inlined.

Comment: I have not heard that bit-field is not portable. Isn't it standard thing? And unfortunately, I should write code only in C :(. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: The layout is not portable. You never know how your "imm17" and "shamt" fields for example overlap.

Comment: What I know is that the latter bit-field occupies more significant bits. I think, then, I know the layout, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you! I understand what you said. :)